# Mapbox mapbox-gl-geocoder container overlaps results

Tags: javascript, css, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have 2 standard mapbox mapbox-gl-geocoder containers one over another. And when the search results from the first one appears in the drop down list, the second container overlays the results.
I tried css z-index 1000 over li, ul etc., but nothing works. Now I ended up with

```
geocoderStart.on('results', function(ev) {
            document.getElementById('geocoderEnd').style.visibility = "hidden";
        });
        geocoderStart._inputEl.addEventListener('input', function (e) { document.getElementById('geocoderEnd').style.visibility = "hidden"; });
        geocoderStart._inputEl.addEventListener('blur', function (e) { document.getElementById('geocoderEnd').style.visibility = "visible"; });
```

but it is buggy. Is there a simple css way to overlay second input with li results? Thanks

My Code

```
const geocoderStart = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
            countries: 'us',
            marker : false,
            flyTo : false,
            placeholder : "Starting point",
        });
        const geocoderEnd = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
            countries: 'us',
            marker : false,
            flyTo : false,
            placeholder : "Destination point",
        });

        document.getElementById('geocoderEnd').appendChild(geocoderEnd.onAdd(map));
        document.getElementById('geocoderStart').appendChild(geocoderStart.onAdd(map));
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding the following CSS:

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder:first-child {
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

to your implementation. When you add the geocoder instances to the map by executing

```
map.addControl(geocoderStart); 
map.addControl(geocoderEnd);
```

, two DOM elements with `class="mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder mapboxgl-ctrl"` are added as children of the `div` with `class="mapboxgl-ctrl-top-right"` (unless an alternate [`position`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addcontrol) is specified when the `MapboxGeocoder` is instantiated). As shown in the source code for the `mapbox-gl-geocoder` plugin [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/blob/4b52a38652d9fa42e651cb1b568d2e9b4a093c81/lib/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css#L81), the `z-index` of the `.suggestions` class is `1000`, so by setting the `z-index` of the `geocoderStart` object (the first child of the `mapbox-ctrl-top-right` DOM element) to `1001` with the above CSS, the suggestions dropdown of the `geocoderStart` will sit on top of the `geocoderEnd`.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the solution in action: https://jsfiddle.net/njevh376/ (note that you will have to add your own Mapbox access token to view the result).

That being said, from the naming conventions being used in your code (namely `geocoderStart`, `"Starting point"`, `geocoderEnd`, and `"Destination point"`), it looks like you are trying to implement a way to integrate geocoding and directions with your GL JS map. You could use the `mapbox-gl-directions` plugin instead of trying to re-implement a similar solution. As shown in [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/mapbox-gl-directions/), the plugin makes it easy to add this functionality to your map in just a few short lines of code. There are also several options for customization and extension of the plugin, as detailed [here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/blob/master/API.md).